Does spark connector fetch results in parallel
Suppose I use spark connector to connect to opensearch. If I run a search query and result is big. Does spark allows us to get the results in parallel from multiple executors, or, it is something controlled by the opensearch? We don't want to get result record sequentially and then split to spark partitions.
Say, if we do df.searchOpensearch().conversion1(). Does spark automatically put search results into multiple partitions/executors and then do conversion1?
Even if this is parallelized, there is network communication between spark and Opensearch. I am curious if it is worthy using Spark to search Lucene index ourselves.
Thank you.
